# Unfurl links blocks template

Tags: slack-api

I'm using the `link_shared` events to unfurl links in my workspace, trying to generate a template that is as close to Slack's unfurling template as possible, but I have several issues -

1. Blocks have very large spacing between them, causing my 3 blocks to take a lot of space
2. I'm unable to have an image inlined with the text for the title, unless I'm using `context`, but this is causing the text to be very small.

Taking [Slack's example](https://slack.com/help/articles/204399343-Share-links-and-set-preview-preferences) of how link unfurling should look like and trying to [mimic it with blocks](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/T02LE2W2DLP#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22:pager:%20*Slack*%22%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22*%3Chttps://slack.com/features%7CFeatures%3E*%22%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22image%22,%22title%22:%7B%22type%22:%22plain_text%22,%22text%22:%22Slack%20is%20where%20work%20flows.%20It%27s%20where%20the%20people%20you%20need,%20the%20information%20you%20share,%20and%20the%20tool%20you%20use%20come%20together%20to%20get%20things%20done.%22,%22emoji%22:true%7D,%22image_url%22:%22https://a.slack-edge.com/13f94ee/marketing/img/homepage/self-serve-campaign/unfurl/img-unfurl-ss-campaign.jpg%22,%22alt_text%22:%22GitHub%22%7D%5D%7D) should explain the differences. This is the blocks message, and [here you can see the result as an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWm1B.png)

So my main question is - does Slack use some internal blocks formatting not available in the API, or is it possible to achieve the same result?

Thanks a lot!

```
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":pager: *Slack*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "*<https://slack.com/features|Features>*"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "image",
            "title": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Slack is where work flows. It's where the people you need, the information you share, and the tool you use come together to get things done.",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "image_url": "https://a.slack-edge.com/13f94ee/marketing/img/homepage/self-serve-campaign/unfurl/img-unfurl-ss-campaign.jpg",
            "alt_text": "Slack"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It took a bit of playing around, but I realized Slack is actually using [message attachments](https://api.slack.com/reference/messaging/attachments) (the legacy version of message formatting) in order to generate their link unfurls.

For example, if you want to unfurl a GitHub repository link, this is the payload you should send, and it'll generate an almost identical unfurling to what Slack is generating (a small `Added by {app-name}` will be added to the footer) -

```
unfurls["https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-js/"] = {
    author_name: "GitHub",
    author_icon: "https://a.slack-edge.com/80588/img/unfurl_icons/github.png",
    title: "GitHub - slackapi/bolt-js: A framework to build Slack apps using JavaScript",
    title_link: "https://github.com/slackapi/bolt-js/",
    text:  "A framework to build Slack apps using JavaScript. Contribute to slackapi/bolt-js development by creating an account on GitHub.",
    image_url: "https://opengraph.githubassets.com/3e06f7eee96f05a53cd4905af3b296dfe333be7a902bb3e6a095770e87fd17fe/slackapi/bolt-js"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That example is not using the Slack block unfurl - it's an example of how a generic link would be displayed using the page's meta tags to display some additional information, using the favicon image.

If you wanted to create something similar you could use use a markdown block and an image block (like [this](https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/THQH373ND#%7B%22blocks%22:%5B%7B%22type%22:%22section%22,%22text%22:%7B%22type%22:%22mrkdwn%22,%22text%22:%22%F0%9F%A4%96%20*%3Chttps://slack.com/features%7CFeatures%3E*%5CnSlack%20is%20where%20work%20flows...%22%7D%7D,%7B%22type%22:%22image%22,%22image_url%22:%22https://cdn.zappy.app/7f42bf0b1b0593d6aa8fec58823c8394.png%22,%22alt_text%22:%22slack_image%22%7D%5D%7D)) - but the file size would be displayed on a new line rather than after the text.